# In Gremlin, is it possible to split remote/local traversal?

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

[As Gremlin currently does not support case-insensitive predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103202/1189885), I would like to experiment with the performance of running part of my traversal on a remote (in this case, Neptune) that does not support lambda steps, then "transferring" the remainder of the traversal to run locally. Is this possible at all? If so, how do I express "perform this part on the remote, then slurp and run locally"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Java Gremlin client then any subgraph you return using the Gremlin `subgraph` step will be returned as a `TinkerGraph` object. You can then create a new graph traversal source for that graph and process it locally. I have done this myself in the past when I wanted to cache parts of my graph in local memory.

As an alternative, Neptune does support using an Elastic Search cluster to help with full text search type queries.

Comment: The Neptune/ES integration is not practically workable for startup-sized projects; the administration is complex, and it's hideously expensive for the gain of "case-insensitive prefix search". I'll examine the `subgraph` option, which might be the way to go.

Comment: Another alternative is to store a second version of your properties with forced case (lower/upper) just for searching.

Comment: @TaylorRiggan That's the approach I ended up implementing.